# Exponential form of prime factorization in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have to Convert positive integer number into its prime factorization form exponentially. For example:[(2,1), (5,1)] is the correct prime factorization of 10 as defined above.
I have this below code to generate factors.Now I should make them prime and should return their exponents also in tuples . Pl help me.

```
         def primes(n):
             divisors = [ d for d in range(2,n//2+1) if n % d == 0]
             return divisors
```

Comment: in the end you want prime factors with their exponents ?

Comment: yes for example: 10 is our number, result should be 2^1,5^1

Comment: Have a look at the link in my answer.

Comment: you could consider accepting the answer if it answered your question. If you have doubts you can comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly follow the following approach which is **O(n^(1/2))** in time complexity.

```
         # n is the number to be factorized
         # this list holds your desired answer 
         prime_factors = []
         # this variable iterates over prime
         start = 2
         while start*start <= n:
              if n % start == 0:
                 expo = 0
                 while n % start == 0:
                     expo = expo + 1
                     n = n / start
                 prime_factors.append([start,expo])
         if n > 1:
             prime_factors.append([n,1])
         print prime_factors
```

This is a simple iterative method. Here is running version [Prime Factorization](http://ideone.com/e.js/wktsBJ). Click on right upper corner ( fork ) to run on your test case
n = 10. Can run on others also.

Comment: you drop the line `start = start + 1`